# IF condition in PHP is not working correctly.

Tags: php

I just need to check whether my `$_SESSION['member-type']` have 1 or 0 in php.

So I right my IF condition like this:

```
if (($_SESSION['member_type'] != 1) OR ($_SESSION['member_type'] != 0)) {
    echo "<h2>You are not authorized to access this page.</h2>";
    exit();
}
```

But it always echoing `<h2>` string.

What is the wrong in this IF condition?

Comment: @Rizier123 what you meant?

Comment: The conditional says "If it doesn't equal one, or it doesn't equal zero".  It can't equal zero and one at the same time, so it'll always echo.

Comment: @user3733831 Change your condition from `!=` -> `==` !!

Comment: You probably want to use `&&` (logical AND) instead of `OR` - if the member type is not 0 AND it's not 1, echo the message.

Comment: @Rizier123, I tried it like this `if (($_SESSION['member_type'] != 1) OR ($_SESSION['member_type'] == 0))`

Comment: But its not working. Actually I need if member type = 1 or 0 script should be work. If not it should not be work.

Comment: @user3733831 **2x** `!=` -> `==` change both comparison!

Comment: @Rizier123, You mean like this - `if (($_SESSION['member_type'] == 1) OR ($_SESSION['member_type'] == 0))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should satisfy your condition

```
if (($_SESSION['member_type'] != 1) && ($_SESSION['member_type'] != 0)) {
        echo "<h2>You are not authorized to access this page.</h2>";
        exit();
}
```

or

```
$arr_allowed_ids = array(0,1);
if (!in_array($_SESSION['member_type'],$arr_allowed_ids)) {
            echo "<h2>You are not authorized to access this page.</h2>";
            exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using 'or' and '!=' - one of your evaluations will always be true, and therefore `<h2>` will always be echoed.  If any value equals 1, then it is not equal to 0 and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code & i came to know that that if the session variable is NULL the if condition fails.

```
if ((isset($_SESSION['member_type'])
    &&(($_SESSION['member_type'] != 1)
    OR($_SESSION['member_type'] != 0))) 
{
    echo "<h2>You are not authorized to access this page.</h2>";
    exit();
}
```